# Force UIKeyboardAppearance Reload

Tags: ios, uitextview, uikeyboard

I'm working on an iOS app that uses dark keyboards. One such keyboard is affiliated with a UITextView. I create the UITextView and play around with it for a bit and every thing works as it should.

The problem occurs when I dismiss the keyboard and then click the home button and dismiss the app into the background. By reopening my app, I return to the screen on which I just was. When I click on the UITextView, it gives it firstResponder status and the UIKeyboard reappears.

If you check the properties of the UIKeyboard, the appearance is still set to dark but for the first second the keyboard is on the screen it shows as light.

Does anyone know how to force a refresh of the keyboard between the app entering the foreground and the keyboard being displayed?

Comment: Funny I just had a simple textField/keyboard app to test something else. I did as you did - set the style to dark, opened it, and (using the simulator) activated the home button, then tapped the icon to switch back to the app (which was still running). the same view was there, and the keyboard was still up.

Comment: Sorry, @DavidH. I should have mentioned I dismissed the keyboard before sending the app to the background. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is anything you can do at this time to fix this. I had a simple project I had just done to send in a bug report to Apple, but it didn't fail in the demo project as it does in my code. I was going to toss that project away when I saw your problem.

So I have verified that even in the very latest unreleased Xcode and iOS beta this still happens. But, since I had the project already, I did enter a bug report on it with the demo project so Apple can see it for themselves.

15586497 "Keyboard flashes from white to dark under one specific test"

If you want to enter your own bug you can say its a dup of the number above, then no need for a demo project.

IMHO, these things do get fixed, but not for a while - maybe iOS 8 if you're lucky, so I think you're just going to have to live with it, or switch to using a white keyboard.

Comment: Thanks. My team came to the same conclusion and reported it to Apple, as well.

Comment: Well, let me know your bug # if you don't plan to add mine to your bug report - it will be of use to Apple to get two reports, and to save them some time by linking them now.